# How to set MapRoute In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Please see my requirement below.

I want to redirect user to account/login page with follwing conditions.

1. If users types for example http://example.com/Customer1

Where customer1 is customer I am keeping this in one config table where I am having connection string for customer1

so basically customer1  I need to check if this exist in db then redirect to  /Customer1/account/login page.

Please let me know if this possible or not? If yes how I can set or check this map.route?

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            string CurrentURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

                var subdomain = CurrentURL.Split('/')[5];
                var getDB = (from c in dbcontext.Configuration
                             where c.CustomerName == subdomain
                             select new
                                 {
                                     DBName = c.CustomerDBName,
                                     DBUserName = c.CustomerDBUserName,
                                     DBPassword = c.CustomerDBPassword,
                                     DBDataSource = c.CustomerDBDataSource,
                                     DBConnectionString = c.CustomerDBConnectionStringName
                                 }).FirstOrDefault();

                dbcontext.ChangeDatabase(initialCatalog: getDB.DBName, 
                         userId: getDB.DBUserName, 
                         password: getDB.DBPassword, 
                         dataSource: getDB.DBDataSource, 
                         configConnectionStringName: getDB.DBConnectionString);

            return View();
}
```

In above code I am just checking that if subdomain entred by user is macthing then chnage the EDMX connection but now how to redirect to login page customer name.

customer1/Account/Login

Comment: do you have folder/area of something with customer1 which have account/login action other than the default account/login? what does customer1 represent?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Miller. see  suppose if any one types this exmaple.com/customer1 then I need to check in my db if customer1 is present in or db or not. if yes then I need to take connection string from that table and need to redirect to user to exmaple.com/customer1/account/login where account is a controller and login is a view?

Comment: So that end user will login first here example.com/cusotmer1/account/login then if login is ok then if i have redirect to exmaple.com/customer1/home/index.

Comment: So you have a table in the DB, you are checking if `customer1` exists in the rows. if it exists then it fetch the connection string. and you want to redirect to login page to fetch the userid and password for the connection to the DB?

Comment: I have to check if customer1 exist then through config table I need to set the db for this customer1 then this it will redirect to example.com/customer1/account/login then now we are connected to customer1 db now customer1 users can login and once login it will go to example.com/customer1/home/index. so just imagine you have 100 customers now any one customer can request like example.com/customer78 and then if it presents in db then connect customer78 db then redirect to example.com/customer78/account/login. hope I am clear now?

Comment: any idea how to set map.route for this kind of case?

Comment: you need to have a controller and need to set the route for that controller.

Comment: Any idea to force the url to go to the customer1/account/login

Comment: As I can not keep customer1 as contoller as this will keep on chaging if cuomer increases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is

Add a controller Customer

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Customer/

    public ActionResult Default(string id)
    { 

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            return View("SiteIndex"); //default View for you site like home/index here

        //put your code to check the customer in the DB here
         return View();
    }

}
```

in the Route.Config. add the route for customer before the default one.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "CustomerDefault",
              url: "{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
```

Comment: Hi Miller, Thanks for your time. The Customer url is working fine but any RedirectToAction("Index","Home") is not doing anything. I mean it is not doing any redirect. But if I run the url manually like localhost/Home/Index it works fine and goes to the Index view. Has the Map route got some issues?

Comment: Thanks Miller. I think something wrong with Map Route. Actually I just realised that once I am on the first customer view and then calling RedirectToAction("Index","Home") is again redirecting to Customer/Default so seems something wrong with the Map Route.

Comment: we have only parameter in the url and it loops through it. so we must return a view inside the if condition if there is not value in the parameter instead of redirecting.

Comment: the first one in the route map would be executed if we have multiple match.

Comment: I am pasting the code so that I can explain it /Route Config -

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "AccountDefault",
              url: "{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Login(string id)
        {

            if (id != null)
            {
                //DB code
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.Login user)
        {
            
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            
        }
}

Comment: //Home Controller

 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}

Comment: //Login View is the first view which shows the username/password screena nd login button. Now on click of login button it is still staying on the page Login but it should redirect to Home/Index. Please let me know what is wrong?

Comment: you need to handle the home/index and customerx/home/index separately.

Comment: Also consider seperate controller for customers action like i did in the code. You may need to add maproute for Customer3/Home/Index etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply? But how? Can you please give me some sample code.

Comment: But Customer3, cutomer4, customer5 .... to customer n would be dynamic. so I do not see adding customers controller would help me.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
              name: "CustomerDefault",
              url: "{id}/Home/{action}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );

Comment: we are using {id} in url, this is the parameter you passed after www.example.com, so it is dynamic